# How to configure Next.js project to use @Atlaskit open source React UI library (Compile Time Error)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, atlaskit

I am using Next.js version 8 with Atlaskit but getting compile time error which you see as below, I tried many bubble plugin and web-pack configs but didn't work as I am new to web-pack and bubble

```
/Users/UserName/Desktop/work-space/with-styled-components-app/node_modules/@atlaskit/theme/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { css } from 'styled-components';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/work-space/with-styled-components-app/node_modules/@atlaskit/icon/cjs/components/Icon.js:30:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

and my package.json has these dependencies

```
"@atlaskit/avatar": "^15.0.1",
    "@atlaskit/css-reset": "latest",
    "@atlaskit/icon": "^16.0.5",
    "@atlaskit/logo": "^10.0.1",
    "@atlaskit/navigation-next": "5.0.1",
    "@atlaskit/theme": "^8.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.3.1",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.17",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.0-2",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.0.0"
```

Comment: post your `next.config.js` file

Comment: and your `.babelrc` file too

Comment: ```{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}```

Comment: please edit the question.

Comment: the above is my .bablrc but next.config.js I just erase it.

Comment: Have you done the following in `next.config.js` file.  `const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()`

Comment: I put the code you post in comment earlier in my next.config.js but getting this error

Comment: ```Note that pages will be compiled when you first load them.
TypeError: sheet.seal is not a function
    at _callee$ (/Users/Name/Desktop/work-space/with-styled-components-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:2366:23)
    at tryCatch (/Users/Name/Desktop/work-space/with-styled-components-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/Name/Desktop/work-space/with-styled-components-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)```

Comment: is this your `_document.js` https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

Comment: yes this is the same _document.js as I have

Comment: can you make a github repo?